# Obtaining an original SVG viewBox via javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

Our system loads SVG files programmatically into HTML via AJAX.  A typical SVG file begins with:

```
 <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0,0 65415,41616' xml:space='preserve' height='50.000cm'  width='50.000cm' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink
```

But strangely in JavaScript there seems to be no way of getting this 'viewBox' back from the SVG DOM - either as a string, or as a set of values.  Under Mozilla, for example,  firebug reports that the svg node has 5 of the 6 attributes we specifiy - namely: xmlns, xml:space, height, width and xmlns:xlink.  But **ViewBox** is conspicuously missing from this list.

Is there anyway to programmatically retrieve this value? - where is it in the SVG DOM? (We cannot introduce 3rd party libraries).

Comment: I had this question and the answer was extremely useful to me. It would be nice to have details about why it was closed.

Comment: same here... voting to reopen.

Comment: The question was closed because the OP found that they were calling removeAttribute on the viewBox. They wrote an answer to say that but it was deleted by a mod.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at the [`SVGFitToViewBox`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGFitToViewBox) interface, which specifies the [`viewBox`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGFitToViewBox__viewBox) property. The interface for `svg` elements, [`SVGSVGElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#InterfaceSVGSVGElement), extends that interface, so this property is available on the element objects:

```js
const svgElement = document.getElementById("example-svg");
const {x, y, width, height} = svgElement.viewBox.baseVal;
```

Comment: No solution?  Just links?

Comment: `svg.viewBox.baseVal.width` to get the width. Idem for `x`, `y`, and `height`

Answer (score 60):

1. Go to http://phrogz.net/SVG/svg_in_xhtml5.xhtml
2. Open your web browser console
3. Type the code:

   ```js
   var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
   var box = svg.getAttribute('viewBox');
   box.split(/\s+|,/);
   ```
4. Observe the glorious response:

   ```js
   ["-350", "-250", "700", "500"]
   ```
5. Alternatively, type the code:

   ```
   var box = svg.viewBox.baseVal;
   [ box.x, box.y, box.width, box.height ]
   ```
6. Observe the glorious response:

   ```js
   [ -350, -250, 700, 500 ]
   ```

In other words: yes, you can get the viewBox from the DOM, both as a [standard DOM 2 attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-666EE0F9)  as well as an [explicit ECMASCript binding](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#__svg__SVGFitToViewBox__viewBox).

Comment: That's what I tried originally. So I just tried it again but
var box = svg.getAttribute('viewBox'); gets me an 'undefined' even though the svg element is plainly the right node in the debugger. Other attributes like 'height' can be retrieved this way but not 'viewBox'. Its just plain weird.

Comment: The other approach, svg.viewBox.baseVal, gets me a '0,0,0,0' box.  My issues may relate to loading SVG via Ajax

Comment: I have this same issue, no Ajax involved.

Comment: 1. Ask about "Obtaining an original SVG viewBox via javascript
"
2. Observe the glorious response.

Comment: @TonyEastwood no your issue does not relate to Ajax - look more as if you did not define the Attribute viewBox.

Answer (score 1):

Even easier, put an id in your svg then :

```
document.getElementById("your_id").getAttribute("viewBox");
```

Answer (score -1):

Above receipes gave me all zeros for the x, y, width and height viewBox attributes -- unless at least one of them was changed programmatically.

I finally succeded with

```
var width = document.getElementById("mysvg").getAttribute("width");
```

Comment: The width attribute is unrelated to the `viewBox` if both are specified.